# How to resolve the error for the below Python code Error : IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python, algorithm, pycharm

```
# Python 3 implementation of the approach 

# Linearly search x in arr[]. If x is present 
# then return the index, otherwise return -1 
 
 def search(arr, n, x): 
 for i in range(n): 
     if arr[i] == x: 
        return i 
 return -1

# Driver Code 
arr = [1, 10, 30, 15] 
 x = 30
 n = len(arr) 
print(x, "is present at index",search(arr, n, x))
```

How to resolve the error for the Above Python code Error : IndentationError: expected an indented block This code is designed to check and return an array value.

Comment: Python uses indentation (the spaces at the beginning of each line) to know what code goes together. Therefore,  the `for i in range(n)` needs to be indented more than the `def search`.  Also `x = 30` is not allowed to be more indented than `arr = ...`

Comment: You should learn the basic of python syntax (and so indentation, which is basic in python). In your case. `def` start at column 2 (should start at column 1), but also driver code: it should all start at column 1

Comment: @Ajay i have updated your code and resolve the indentation error

Comment: See [this doc](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) about Python and indentation

Comment: @UmairMubeen Thank you, I'm able to compile now.

Comment: @JohanC Thank you for the document & can you please suggest documents to learn efficient python programming and algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow basic indentation while writing python code..
refer https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html

```
def search(arr, n, x): 
 for i in range(n): 
     if arr[i] == x: 
        return i 
 return -1

# Driver Code 
arr = [1, 10, 30, 15] 
x = 30
n = len(arr) 
print(x, "is present at index",search(arr, n, x))
```

Comment: this should not be the answer because you should explain where the indentation error is occur